# A very simple spy with Sinon.JS (on a global module call)... not working, what's wrong?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai, sinon

My test subject is `loader.ts`:

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

export class SimpleLoader {
  public load() {
    dotenv.config(); // I want to spy on this call
  }
}
```

So, using Sinon.JS (together with Mocha & Chai) I did the following in `loader.spec.ts`:

```js
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

describe('SimpleLoader', function() {
  // First spy on, then require SimpleLoader
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.dotenvSpy = sinon.spy(dotenv, 'config');
    this.SimpleLoader = require('./loader').SimpleLoader;
  });

  it('loads correctly using default options', function() {
    const loader = new this.SimpleLoader();
    loader.load(); // the call that should call the spy!

    console.log(this.dotenvSpy.getCalls()); // NOT WORKING - no calls, empty array []
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.dotenvSpy.restore();
  });
});
```

The problem is that stub is never called.

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce the issue

Comment: likewise, I couldn't reproduce the issue too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example, just change `import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'` to `import dotenv from 'dotenv'`:

`loader.ts`:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

export class SimpleLoader {
  public load() {
    dotenv.config();
  }
}
```

`loader.spec.ts`:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('SimpleLoader', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.dotenvSpy = sinon.spy(dotenv, 'config');
    this.SimpleLoader = require('./loader').SimpleLoader;
  });

  it('loads correctly using default options', function() {
    const loader = new this.SimpleLoader();
    loader.load();
    expect(this.dotenvSpy.calledOnce).to.be.true;
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    this.dotenvSpy.restore();
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  SimpleLoader
    ✓ loads correctly using default options


  1 passing (152ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 loader.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 loader.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56427984